# Prettify my URLs with PHP

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, friendly-url

I'm writing a site in PHP that I would like to have structures, nice, and pretty URLs in.  I know in one site I had rules setup in the `.htaccess`, but I have to have some of these URL rules created dynamically, so is there a way to do that in the PHP itself?  I feel like Wordpress does this somehow with its pages.

Basically, if I go to this page:

`site.com/users/Xan`

it will technically be loading:

`site.com/users?name=Xan`

I can write the patterns (using regex) fairly easily.  I just need to know how to make this possible.

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1:**

To redirect using .htaccess to /users enter this in:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ users?user=$1 [L,QSA]
```

You can then get your username as $user by simply doing:

```
$user = $_GET['user'];
```

**Option 2:**

If that's not what you're after and you're looking to redirect /users/username to $_GET['page'] in the index.php, stick this into your .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

So let's explode that response in PHP:

```
$urlarray = explode("/",$_GET['page']);
```

Now

```
echo $urlarray[0]; // users
```

And...

```
echo $urlarray[1]; // username
```